# App Store Testing in Simulator

Tags: xcode, app-store

It appears that the IOS simulator is unable to download anything from the App Store.

I have an app that I switched from having built-in -data to using data downloaded from the app store. Without data, the app does nothing.

Am I now precluded from testing in the simulator?

or is there some way to manually downloading an in app purchase into the app, then testing post purchase?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you pretty much answered your own question. The simulator is not supposed to download things.

Comment: The question is whether there is some work around to simulate downloads to get over that hurdle.

Comment: No, if you can't download, then you can't download. What would actually be the benefit of being able to download your app from the appStore while you have it on your Mac too?

Comment: But is there some way to realistically create a download package and install it in the app manually? Or is that too much of a PITA?